# All partitions wiped, USB Debugging was not enabled, ADB and fastboot can not see Nexus 5

Tags: nexus-5, bootloader, partitions, twrp

I got my shiny new Nexus 5 a couple of weeks ago and decided i wanted to root. I rooted using fastboot on my Ubuntu box.

---

I then installed [MultiRom](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tassadar.multirommgr&hl=en) and from there I installed Ubuntu touch.
Everything was going fine and dandy until I changed the kernel to CM 11 and rebooted to apply the changes. It didn't boot so I opened up my TWRP recovery that multirom had installed and decided it was a good idea to erase all the partitions to try and fix this kernel issue. That didn't work so I plugged it into my computer and ran

> fastboot reboot-bootloader
>
> Waiting for device ...

It never rebooted.
I also can't do anything with either fastboot or adb when before it worked fine.
TWRP works fine and i can navigate around in that easily. MTP will never activate. I didn't have usb debugging enabled. My bootloader is unlocked.

Please Help

Comment: Could you please provide an update about your current situation?

Comment: Download a flashable ROM zip, and if your phone supports OTG or external SD card, then transfer the zip into OTG drive or SD card, plug into the phone, use TWRP to flash the image, and enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

@Hellreaver
Actually: Not yet a brick.
I managed to install a custom ROM along the lines explained here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6m5pJSYm19I
Flashing from the USB stick was still possible, since I had TWRP 3.3.1-0 already installed on my Samsung S6 G920F.

Answer (score -1):

You bricked your device. You could try reformatting with recovery and finding the factory image for your device, then flashing via recovery from SD card (does it take one?) twrp has and always will suck, in my opinion.